# Binding implementation for XML layout is not generated if 2-way Data Binding through Converters is used

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-databinding, two-way-binding

I have an **AppCompatAutoEditTextView** in my layout. This view is populated from an enum class called **FlavorType** using ArrayAdapter.

Now, I want to implement 2-way DataBinding, with the text attribute being bound to a MutableLiveData. For this to work, I implemented the following **Converter**:

```
object Converter {
    @InverseMethod(value = "flavor_str_to_enum")
    fun flavor_enum_to_str(view: AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView, value: FlavorType): String {
        return when (value) {
            FlavorType.SWEET -> view.context.getString(R.string.label_flavor_sweet)
            FlavorType.SAVORY -> view.context.getString(R.string.label_flavor_savory)
            FlavorType.NONE -> view.context.getString(R.string.label_none)
            else -> view.context.getString(R.string.label_none)
        }
    }

    fun flavor_str_to_enum(view: AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView, value: String): FlavorType {
        return when (value) {
            view.context.getString(R.string.label_flavor_sweet) -> FlavorType.SWEET
            view.context.getString(R.string.label_flavor_savory) -> FlavorType.SAVORY
            view.context.getString(R.string.label_none) -> FlavorType.NONE
            else -> FlavorType.NONE
        }
    }
}
```

After this, in my XML for my view, I added the following line:

```
android:text="@={Converter.INSTANCE.flavor_enum_to_str(viewmodel.flavor)}
```

where, flavor is of type MutableLiveData. Also, I added import tags for my Converter class at the top of the XML.

Now, for some reason unknown to me, just by adding the above line in my xml, my build starts failing with a **cannot find symbol error** that the **BindingImpl** associated with my XML was not found. I looked in the generated code folders and yes, the **Fragment...BindingImpl** for my xml is not there while for other layouts they are present. Just by removing the above line of code, everything starts working again. I have tried everything, invalidating, restarting, etc. But, this issue still seems to persist.

Can anyone provide insights into, what could be happening or what I might be doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Running gradle build with **--stacktrace**, I get the following error:

```
[databinding] {"msg":"cannot find method flavor_enum_to_str(dev.example.myapp.model.FlavorType) in class dev.example.myapp.utils.Converter","file":"app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_addrecipe.xml","pos":[{"line0":119,"col0":41,"line1":119,"col1":86}]}
```

This leads me to believe that it's trying to look up the above mentioned function signature, but instead it finds:

```
flavor_enum_to_str(AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView, FlavorType)
```

I followed the documentation and implemented things the way it described.

Comment: Could you please add `@JvmStatic` annotation and try.

Comment: I tried this, but I still get the same error.